# Bootstrap or jquery stopping form SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Tired to make this parallax with bootstrap and jquery.. but FORM is not submitting while this code works fine separately if I run.. If someone can help me out in this..

Here is page : http://cellsouq.com/xtra/co/ (complete code)
Click on OPPORTUNITIES > FRANCHISE (on top navigation)
Click on APPLY ... it will scroll to FORM

Form is something like that with javascript

```
<script>
function funcFranchise() {
    alert('Submitted Successfull');
    // To validate form elements
}
</script> 

<form onSubmit="return funcFranchise(this)" class="form-horizontal" >
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit Request" class="btn bg-primary" >
</form>
```

If i remove Bootstrap it works fine. In whole code somewhere submit EVENT is blocked not sure... Please help me out..

Comment: the function you call is inconsistent. 
you declared `funcFranchise()` but you call `funcFranchise(this)`.  change `funcFranchise(this)` to `funcFranchise()` and try again.

Comment: Hi you have two outstanding error in the console. Solve them first? JavaScript can be sensitive to halt the rest when there is an error.

Comment: correct but still if i declare with arg .. still not work,,, if you could check why SUBMIT not working it would great help ;0

Comment: funcFranchise(frm) ... done but still not working...

Comment: @EricT which 2 errors?? can you please specify.

Comment: console error fixed but still form not submitting..

Comment: @bekt tried but not working..

Comment: Hi, you have 1 more error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined". After that try to have proper <form> tag for example : <form name="blabla" action="asdasd.php" method="post">

Comment: i just tested.. on this page <a href is also not working.. jquery or bootstrap stopping it.. this is actual matter

Comment: i test your page by run `$('.form-horizontal').submit()` from browser js console. and it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should return either `true` or `false` upon the completion your validations. So try like;

```
<script>
function funcFranchise() {
    alert('Submitted Successfull');
    // To validate form elements
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function funcFranchise() {
alert('Submitted Successfull');
// To validate form elements
$('.form-horizontal').submit();
```

}

Comment: i just tested.. on this page <a href is also not working.. jquery or bootstrap stopping it.. this is actual matter

Comment: can you post your whole html if its not an issue

Comment: i already posted FULL HTML/CSS/JQUERY there http://cellsouq.com/xtra/co/ ... if you could have a look and try to solve.. plz